# how to find the nearest agent based on distance?

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to make that when an agent is less than a specified distance from any other, they change color. But when I use `getNearestAgent(this.getPopulation())` it gives me the Agent in the position 0 of the population list.
I'm using an event to make the agents change color.
[this is the code of the event and the output of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSnFU.png)

and the color change depends of the rate of the event and sometimes the distance from the point (0,0,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `distanceTo()` function.

Each agent will need to loop through all the other agents and then check their distance to the other agents.

[image]

Comment: I was working on this problem and it turns out that I made a mistake when setting the rate and in my simulation it looked for the nearest agent once every 100 seconds so it always returned agent [0] as the nearest one